# find String of an Array that is in an array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Ok, so I have a array

```
String[] sound = new String[2]
sound[0] = nameSound;
sound[1] = routeSound;
```

and this Array is in an Array

```
String[] Sounds[]= new String[1][]; 

Sounds[0]=sound;
```

I just made an Array, but I will have a lot of arrays

And if the users write nameSound "name", It has to be compared to the nameSound of every vector called sound, when it is found, I want something like

```
 System.out.print(nameSound);
```

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use just 2 for loops. But if the arrays are realy large you must find some more performance optimated way.

```
for(String[] sound : Sounds)
{
    for(String soundName : sound)
    {
        if(soundName.equals(searchString))
        {
             System.out.print(soundName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could of course loop over all nested arrays, the code itself isn't hard. But aren't you actually looking for the functionality of a map where you store the name as key and route as value? Then you could easily find the routeSound by entering the nameSound, while you still have access to the data.

pseudocode:

```
Map<String, String> sounds = new HashMap<String, String)();
sounds.put(nameSound, routeSound);

String foundRouteSound = sounds.get(inputNameSound);
```